# reshaping a complex DF from long to wide with 2 factors (rstudio)

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks pretty much like this one:

```
CLIENT_CODE  TIME  DATE  question1  question2  question3  question4 ....ETC
AA1234         1   12/1      1          3          4        TEXT11
BB1234         1   12/2      0          8          2        TEXT9 
CC1234         1   13/1      NA         3          8        TEXT8
AA1234         2   15/2      6          7          9        TEXT7
BB1234         3   17/3      2          3          7        TEXT6
CC1234         3   21/4      2          5          4        TEXT5
BB1234         2   12/6      9          3          2        TEXT3
CC1234         2   02/7      2          2          1        TEXT2
```

now the thing im trying to to (and was struggling with it a few hours)
is to make the Factor(c_code) as my row (to unite a few c_code into a single row in they match) and
to make the TIME Factor into a column so that each time would have its own answers for question1, question 2, question3... ETC.
pretty much like this:

```
CLIENT_CODE  DATE_1  q1_1  q2_1  q3_1 ...ETC| DATE_2  q1_2  q2_2   q3_2 ...ETC| 
AA1234       12/1     1   3   4  TEXT11     | 15/2     5     4      2         |
BB1234       12/2     0   8   2  TEXT9      | 12/6     2     3      4         |
CC1234       13/1     NA  3   8  TEXT8      | 02/7     3     3      2         |
```

Comment: omg that you :)

Answer (score 0):

it appears that this can be done easily in two steps, though there may be a simpler method that I am missing. To simplify the problem slightly, I have removed the DATE column but this can be added back in after reshaping the data frame if it is entirely necessary. First melt the frame:

```
intermediate <- melt(test, id.vars = c("CLIENT_CODE", "TIME"))
```

This gives a data frame with 4 columns: CLIENT_CODE, TIME, variable, and value. The variable column holds the question number and the value column holds the answer. Then you can cast this intermediate frame to get it into the form that you want.

```
final <- dcast(intermediate, CLIENT_CODE ~ variable + TIME, value.var = "value")
```

This final version holds columns with time-question combinations and the cast function automatically renames columns in the form for which you asked (i.e. "q1_1", "q2_2", etc.), but gives them in a different order, so you may have to rearrange slightly.

Comment: hey Omri, thank you for you answer.
there is a one problem, instead of the values i get only 0 / 1 at the new table.
could it be because of the warning I get whem using the function dcast?
"Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length"

Comment: If it matters, my "value" column hold numbers, text and dated and it is "as.chatacter" class after the "melt" function.